# eclipse javascript files

Tags: javascript, eclipse

i ran the code found here http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-hello-world/ but eclipse doesnt seem to run the jquery code ? i placed the jquery.js file in all the directories found under the project name but still no luck. Where exactly should the .js file go ?

Comment: Try with link from google apis - https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: hey when i open the html file from a browser it works but when i run it inside eclipse it doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The `<script>` tag should go inside `<head>` or `<body>`, not in between. The behaviour is unspecified and thus browser specific (it however works fine for me on Eclipse 3.6 SR2).

As to the location of the `.js` file, the `<script src>` in the code example declares just the filename without a path, so it is supposed to be in the same path/folder as the HTML file.